# The probability of hitting a bird with

Tags: probability

The probability of hitting a bird with a stone lying on a tree by A is $\frac {1}{4}$ and by B is $\frac {3}{5}$. Draw a probability tree diagram to show the probability of all possible ways of hitting the bird.

I couldn't draw the tree diagram. What is the sample space here..???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P(A) = $\frac{1}{4}$

P(A' = Not hitting) = $\frac{3}{4}$

P(B) = $\frac{3}{5}$

P(B' = Not hitting) = $\frac{2}{5}$

There are total three cases -

1. None of them hit -

P(A') * P(B') =  $\frac{3}{4} \times \frac{2}{5} =  \frac{6}{20}$

2. Either of them hit -

P(A) * P(B') + P(A') * P(B) =  $\frac{1}{4} \times  \frac{2}{5} + \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{3}{5} =  \frac{2}{20} + \frac{9}{20} = \frac{11}{20}$

3. Both of them hit -

P(A) * P(B) =  $\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{3}{5} =  \frac{3}{20}$

Sample space = $ \left[ \frac{6}{20}, \frac{11}{20}, \frac{3}{20} \right]$

And you can draw [Probability Tree Diagram with the help of this link.](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-tree-diagrams.html)

Answer (score 2):

I assume $A$ and $B$ are people? Let's go with that.

Imagine $A$ throws a stone; either it hits the bird or not. How do you draw the corresponding tree and branches for these two cases? (**Probability tree**, that is; not the tree with a bird...)

Next, from the two cases of $A$ (i.e., hits the bird or not) you may now consider the two cases of what happens with $B$ throwing their own stone. Similarly, either the stone thrown by $B$ hits or not.

So your possible outcomes are, I think, neither hits the bird, only $A$ hits the bird, only $B$ hits the bird, or both hit the bird. Although, to be realistic, I would think that if the first thrower hits the bird it would alter the probability that the second does, too. (Maybe their throws coincide?) And to be *very* realistic, probably one should avoid throwing stones at birds (and glass houses) altogether.

Comment: Throwing stones at glass houses is malicious. Throwing stones when you live in a glass house is foolish. I agree that both should be avoided.

Comment: @EthanBolker And the same for throwing glass when you live in a stone house!

Comment: Or at stone houses.

Comment: @Benjamin, Could you show the.figure please?

Comment: @user354073 Where is your *own* attempt? Please insert what you have already tried into your original post; thanks!